# Will Nvidia and Catalyst drivers conflict with each other?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, software-conflict

I currently have a Sapphire R9-280x in my computer and was thinking about putting my EVGA Gtx 670 back in to see if it would work better (long story). I want to know if the Nvidia and Catalyst drivers will conflict with each other if I were to test my Nvidia card.

Comment: **You should removed the Catalyst drivers before you try this.**  It takes no effort to do so.

Comment: I've had a laptop where the manufacturer didn't know whether it came with this hardware or that hardware and said install drivers for both. That said, a person with your two drivers has said he found they conflicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had problems with having both on my computer.  My second monitor runs on of my old ATI card and my main monitor runs on my Nvidia card.  I have to update my ATI card through Device Manager.  I have found this to work the best.  I have had it "work" with both Catalyst and Nvidia's control panel installed, but they literally seemed to fight over my main monitor regardless which card I set it to.